# How to insert multiple rows at once in a table with array of key value pair data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, sql-insert

I want to insert `array()` `key` `value` pair data into a table

```
<?php
$foreignKey = 2;
$array = array(
   'availability' => array(
       array('day' => 'monday','time' => 'am'),
       array('day' => 'wednesday','time' => 'pm'),    
   ),
);
```

My availability table - in the beginning

table:  availability

```
| id  |  foreign_id  |   day  |  time  |
+-----+--------------+--------+--------+
```

resultant table:

```
| id  |  foreign_id  |   day    |  time  |
+-----+--------------+----------+--------+
|  1  |       2      | monday   |  am    |
+-----+--------------+----------+--------+
|  2  |       2      |wednesday |  pm    |
+-----+--------------+----------+--------+


$sql = "INSERT INTO availability ";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through your array and bind and execute

```
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO availability (fld1, fld2) VALUES(?, ?)");
foreach($array as $row)
{
    $stmt->bind_param($row['fld1'], $row['fld2']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
     array('day' => 'monday','time' => 'am'),
     array('day' => 'wednesday','time' => 'pm') 
);

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `availability`(`foreign_id`,  `day`,`time`)VALUES($foreignKey, '$value[day]', '$value[time]') ";
}
```